# How to separate XML nodes into individual pages and add links or a navigation bar to access each page?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm confused on how to do this with a single XML file. For example, I want to go to *blue page*, I would click on the hyperlink blue, and would be directed to *"This page is blue."* Is there a way to do this without using binding?

**XML file**

```
<Colors>
   <Color>
       <description>
           <p>This page is red.</p>
       </description>
   </Color>
   <Color>
       <description>
           <p>This page is blue.</p>
       </description>
   </Color>
   <Color>
       <description>
           <p>This page is green.</p>
       </description>
   </Color>
<Colors>
```

Comment: You need to transform this to HTML, really. Are you actually asking for help with writing an XSL transformation which would transform this XML document into the [HTML] output you are looking for? I also note your first question was very similar to this. Other questions would include; what XML parser are you going to use to do the transformations? What programming languages (like C# or Java) are you familiar with?

Comment: Yes or at least a starting point?

Answer (score 0):

You could use attributes on the color node to signal it's color.
Use linq to find the node whose attribute has the name of the hyperlink target clicked and serve that node's description.